# Can a script resume after computer comes out of hibernation?

Tags: hibernate, perl

I kept a perl script running and then forgot it and hibernated my laptop running Ubuntu. When I restarted it, the script was seen to be running (pleasant surprise!). Is this correct behaviour or did the computer not hibernate properly?

If this is a correct behaviour, how does it work, does it save program state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you hibernate everything freezes in the status you left it (including your script). The script is not running during hibernation it simply resumes as if you actually never put the PC to sleep. All that changes for the script is the current time/date, so if the script relies on that you may have some issues.